# why airflow googlecloudstorageobjectsensor is not serching for the partial object names (eg:file*.csv)

Tags: airflow

gcs_sensor in airflow is not working for the partial object name.
for example in object I have given myfile* but it is not working.
can you suggest a solution that takes partial names to search in the google cloud storage

```
file_watcher = GoogleCloudStorageObjectSensor(
    task_id='filesensor',
    bucket='poc-1',
    object='myfile*',
    google_cloud_conn_id='google_cloud_default',
    dag=example_dag
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look at `GoogleCloudStoragePrefixSensor`.

Reference:

https://airflow.apache.org/_api/airflow/contrib/sensors/gcs_sensor/index.html?highlight=googlecloudstorageprefixsensor#airflow.contrib.sensors.gcs_sensor.GoogleCloudStoragePrefixSensor

```
file_watcher = GoogleCloudStoragePrefixSensor(
    task_id='filesensor',
    bucket='poc-1',
    prefix='myfile',
    google_cloud_conn_id='google_cloud_default',
    dag=example_dag
)
```

Comment: does this keep the dag alive? or does this just check and then success/fail?
Thanks

Comment: @arcee123 It keeps the dag running till a file arrives, as soon as a file arrives, it is marked as success. If you want to wait for longer period in case another file would arrive after some time, you could use the TimeDeltaSensor as well.